# .React material Botton outline have black border-color onclick . But I haven't set it. How do I remove it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export default function DisableElevation() {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" disableElevation >
      Disable elevation
    </Button>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not see any such border here: https://codesandbox.io/s/button-pzyh9?file=/src/App.js. I suggest you inspect the element in the browser developer tools to see where this border style is coming from. I suspect you have some global CSS in your page that is causing this.

Comment: As @RyanCogswell said. This issue is probably due to you importing the bootstrap styles globally, they have a button:focus style that looks exactly like this. Remove that and it should go back to normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also got this issue
[image]

The problem was using both MUI and bootstrap. remove importing 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in project and after remove bootstrap, problem will solve
[image]
you don't need this both libraries for ui dev works you can do most of things by using one. You can use either MUI or bootstrap as your wish but using both in same project cause to UI effects

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Thank you

Comment: Great, one line solution, awesome thanks it's worked for me

Answer (score 6):

It is quite simple just make border:none and outline:none that's it for a corresponding component.

```js
style={{
 border:"none",
 outline:"none"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using material UI. also it has taken a lot of time to figure it out how to remove it after clicking the border. I found a way to remove the border using the below code it will help.

```
"&.MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within": {
      outline: "none",
    },
```